# Trying to authenticate and redirect to private route. Keeps redirecting/refreshing login page instead

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, components, state

I believe the issue is the isAuthenticated state in the parent APP component is not being changed when bcrypt has confirmed credentials in the child Login component. I can't seem to get it to change.
I have added some console.log to see if  change takes place and console.log 2 is skipped over and is never read.
The examples I keep finding pass a value back to parent when it the return() "html" portion of the child component function. I tried to use that as a basis for passing a call to the funciton in the parent to change the state. As I am here that method does not seem to work. Any guidance and/or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

The ideal situation would be after being authenticated by bcrypt, user would be redirected to private route /Post

APP:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from "./Nav";
import About from './About';
import Creater from './Creater';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout} from './components/Layout';
import Home from "./Home";
import Post from "./Post";
import Login from './Login';
function App() {


  

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState (false)

  console.log(isAuthenticated + "1");
    
  function auth () { setIsAuthenticated (true);
    console.log(isAuthenticated + "2");
  } 
  
  console.log(isAuthenticated + "3");

    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props)=>(
        isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props}/>
        : <Redirect to='/login'  />
      )}/>
      )


  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <Layout>
    <Switch>

    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/creater" component={Creater} />
    <Route auth={auth}  path="/login"  component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} path="/post"  component={Post} />
    </Switch>
    </Layout>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}






export default App;
```

Login:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

function Login({auth}) {
 

const [login, setLogin] = useState ({
  adminname: "",
  password: "",
});


function onChangeAdminname (event) {
  setLogin({adminname: event.target.value,
  password: login.password})
}

function onChangePassword (event) {
  setLogin({adminname: login.adminname,
    password: event.target.value})
}


function onSubmit ({event }) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const admin = login.adminname 
  const logpassword = login.password

  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/admins', {
  params: {
    adminname: admin
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
  

  var pw = (response.data);
  
  console.log(response.data);

  bcrypt.compare(logpassword, pw[0].password, function(err, result){
    
    if (result === true) {
console.log(auth);
      auth();
     
      
      window.location.pathname = "/post";
      
     

    } else {
      if(!alert("Admin name or password was incorrect, please try again")){window.location.reload();}
    }

  });
  
  
  
  
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  });

}


    return (

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          
          <form 
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          >
            <div class="form-group">
            
              <input  className="form-control" 
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Admin Name" 
              value={login.adminname}
              onChange={onChangeAdminname}
              name="adminmame"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             
              <input type="password" 
              className="form-control" 
              placeholder="Password" 
              value={login.password}
              onChange={onChangePassword}
              name="password"/>
            </div>
            <button value="POST" type="submit" className="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>






        )
    }




  export default Login;
```

post:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {authenticated} from './Login';
import './App.css';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

function Post() {

const [postDate, setPostDate] = useState(new Date());

const [post, setPost] = useState({
  title: "",
  blog: "",
  date: postDate,
  });
  



function onChangeTitle(event) {

setPost({
  title:  event.target.value,
  blog : post.blog,
date: post.date})
}


function onChangeBlog(event) {

setPost({
  title: post.title,
  blog : event.target.value,
date: post.date})
}

function onChangeDate(date) {

setPostDate(date);


}



function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/posts/add', post)  
  .then(res => console.log(res.data));


window.location = '/';
}



  return (

<div >

<h3>Compose a new post :D</h3>
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

<div className="form-group">
<input type="text"
required
className="form-control form-control-lg"
placeholder="Title"
value={post.title}
onChange={onChangeTitle}/>
</div>
<div>

<textarea type="text"
required
className="form-control  form-control-lg"
rows="10"
placeholder="Tell a story"
value={post.blog}
onChange={onChangeBlog} ></textarea>
</div>


<div className="form-group">
<label>Date: </label>
<div>
<DatePicker

selected={postDate}

onChange={onChangeDate}/>
 </div>
</div>


<div className="form-group">
<input type="submit" value="POST" className="btn btn-primary"/>

</div>


</form>


</div>



  )
}


export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned Bcrypt is not supported in ReactJS however can be used in NodeJS.

The browser supported version for Bcrypt is `npm install bcryptjs`

check their docs here:https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Comment: Hello, I did end up using bcryptjs over bcrypt and before trying to implement the private route it seemed to authenticate correrefty and then redirect to post as planned

Comment: Yes bcryptjs is supported on browser I hope my answer helped and was informative